# Undefined Offset

Tags: php, arrays

I'm a JS guy who is trying his hand at PHP but I've gotten stuck converting a multidimensional array.

It's throwing: Notice: Undefined offset: 90000 on line 268 - which I know means it can't find an index of 99000 in the array, but it's there -- what's gone wrong?

```
$BasicSkedValues = array(-7700.0, -3560.0, 0.0, 6600.0, 7200.0, 7800.0, 8400.0, 9000.0, 9600.0, 10200.0, 10800.0, 11400.0, 12000.0, 12600.0, 13200.0, 13800.0, 14400.0, 15000.0, 15600.0, 16200.0, 16800.0, 17400.0, 18000.0, 18600.0, 19200.0, 19800.0, 20400.0, 21000.0, 21600.0, 22200.0, 22800.0, 23400.0, 24000.0, 24600.0, 25200.0, 25800.0, 26400.0, 27000.0, 27600.0, 28200.0, 28800.0, 29400.0, 30000.0, 30600.0, 31200.0, 31800.0, 32400.0, 33000.0, 33600.0, 34200.0, 34800.0, 35400.0, 36000.0, 36600.0, 37200.0, 37800.0, 38400.0, 39000.0, 39600.0, 40200.0, 40800.0, 41400.0, 42000.0, 42600.0, 43200.0, 43800.0, 44400.0, 45000.0, 45600.0, 46200.0, 46800.0, 47400.0, 48000.0, 48600.0, 49200.0, 49800.0, 50400.0, 51000.0, 51600.0, 52200.0, 52800.0, 53400.0, 54000.0, 54600.0, 55200.0, 55800.0, 56400.0, 57000.0, 57600.0, 58200.0, 58800.0, 59400.0, 60000.0, 60600.0, 61200.0, 61800.0, 62400.0, 63000.0, 63600.0, 64200.0, 64800.0, 65400.0, 66000.0, 66600.0, 67200.0, 67800.0, 68400.0, 69000.0, 69600.0, 70200.0, 70800.0, 71400.0, 72000.0, 72600.0, 73200.0, 73800.0, 74400.0, 75000.0, 75600.0, 76200.0, 76800.0, 77400.0, 78000.0, 78600.0, 79200.0, 79800.0, 80400.0, 81000.0, 81600.0, 82200.0, 82800.0, 83400.0, 84000.0, 84600.0, 85200.0, 85800.0, 86400.0, 87000.0, 87600.0, 88200.0, 88800.0, 89400.0, 90000.0, 90600.0, 91200.0, 91800.0, 92400.0, 93000.0, 93600.0, 94200.0, 94800.0, 95400.0, 96000.0, 96600.0, 97200.0, 97800.0, 98400.0, 99000.0, 99600.0, 100200.0, 100800.0, 101400.0, 102000.0, 102600.0, 103200.0, 103800.0, 104400.0, 105000.0, 105600.0, 106200.0, 106800.0, 107400.0, 108000.0, 108600.0, 109200.0, 109800.0, 110400.0, 111000.0, 111600.0, 112200.0, 112800.0, 113400.0, 114000.0, 114600.0, 115200.0, 115800.0, 116400.0, 117000.0, 117600.0, 118200.0, 118800.0, 119400.0, 120000.0, 120600.0, 121200.0, 121800.0, 122400.0, 123000.0, 123600.0, 124200.0, 124800.0, 125400.0, 126000.0, 126600.0, 127200.0, 127800.0, 128400.0, 129000.0, 129600.0, 130200.0, 130800.0, 131400.0, 132000.0, 132600.0, 133200.0, 133800.0, 134400.0, 135000.0, 135600.0, 136200.0, 136800.0, 137400.0, 138000.0, 138600.0, 139200.0, 139800.0, 140400.0, 141000.0, 141600.0, 142200.0, 142800.0, 143400.0, 144000.0, 144600.0, 145200.0, 145800.0, 146400.0, 147000.0, 147600.0, 148200.0, 148800.0, 149400.0, 150000.0);

function getClosest($search, $BasicSkedValues) {
   $closest = null;
   foreach ($BasicSkedValues as $item) {
      if ($closest === null || abs($search - $closest) > abs($item - $search)) {
         $closest = $item;
      }
   }

   print_r ("The closest is".$closest."<br/>");
   return $closest;
}

//getClosest(10600,$BasicSkedValues); --- This works swimmingly


$BasicSkedMatrix = array(
             "0", array(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), 
          "6600", array(600.0, 600.0, 600.0, 600.0, 600.0, 600.0), 
          "7200", array(600.0, 600.0, 600.0, 600.0, 600.0, 600.0),
          "7800", array(600.0, 600.0, 600.0, 600.0, 600.0, 600.0),
          "8400", array(600.0, 600.0, 600.0, 600.0, 600.0, 600.0),
          "9000", array(849.0, 859.0, 868.0, 878.0, 887.0, 896.0),
          "9600", array(1259.0, 1273.0, 1287.0, 1301.0, 1315.0, 1329.0),
         "10200", array(1669.0, 1687.0, 1706.0, 1724.0, 1743.0, 1761.0),
         "10800", array(2076.0, 2099.0, 2122.0, 2145.0, 2168.0, 2192.0), 
         "11400", array(2331.0, 2505.0, 2533.0, 2560.0, 2588.0, 2616.0), 
         "12000", array(2439.0, 2911.0, 2943.0, 2975.0, 3007.0, 3039.0), 
         "12600", array(2546.0, 3318.0, 3354.0, 3390.0, 3427.0, 3463.0), 
         "13200", array(2654.0, 3724.0, 3765.0, 3806.0, 3846.0, 3887.0), 
         "13800", array(2761.0, 4029.0, 4175.0, 4221.0, 4266.0, 4311.0), 
         "14400", array(2869.0, 4186.0, 4586.0, 4636.0, 4685.0, 4735.0), 
         "15000", array(2976.0, 4342.0, 4996.0, 5051.0, 5105.0, 5159.0), 
         "15600", array(3079.0, 4491.0, 5321.0, 5466.0, 5524.0, 5583.0), 
         "16200", array(3179.0, 4635.0, 5490.0, 5877.0, 5940.0, 6003.0), 
         "16800", array(3278.0, 4780.0, 5660.0, 6254.0, 6355.0, 6423.0), 
         "17400", array(3378.0, 4924.0, 5830.0, 6442.0, 6771.0, 6843.0), 
         "18000", array(3478.0, 5069.0, 5999.0, 6629.0, 7186.0, 7262.0), 
         "18600", array(3578.0, 5213.0, 6169.0, 6816.0, 7389.0, 7682.0), 
         "19200", array(3678.0, 5358.0, 6339.0, 7004.0, 7592.0, 8102.0), 
         "19800", array(3778.0, 5502.0, 6508.0, 7191.0, 7796.0, 8341.0), 
         "20400", array(3878.0, 5647.0, 6678.0, 7378.0, 7999.0, 8558.0), 
         "21000", array(3977.0, 5790.0, 6847.0, 7565.0, 8201.0, 8774.0), 
         "21600", array(4076.0, 5933.0, 7015.0, 7750.0, 8402.0, 8989.0), 
         "22200", array(4176.0, 6075.0, 7182.0, 7936.0, 8602.0, 9204.0), 
         "22800", array(4275.0, 6216.0, 7345.0, 8116.0, 8798.0, 9413.0), 
         "23400", array(4373.0, 6357.0, 7509.0, 8297.0, 8994.0, 9623.0), 
         "24000", array(4471.0, 6498.0, 7672.0, 8478.0, 9190.0, 9832.0), 
         "24600", array(4570.0, 6639.0, 7836.0, 8658.0, 9386.0, 10042.0), 
         "25200", array(4668.0, 6780.0, 8000.0, 8839.0, 9582.0, 10251.0), 
         "25800", array(4767.0, 6920.0, 8163.0, 9020.0, 9778.0, 10461.0), 
         "26400", array(4865.0, 7061.0, 8327.0, 9200.0, 9974.0, 10670.0), 
         "27000", array(4963.0, 7202.0, 8490.0, 9381.0, 10170.0, 10880.0), 
         "27600", array(5054.0, 7332.0, 8642.0, 9548.0, 10351.0, 11074.0), 
         "28200", array(5135.0, 7448.0, 8776.0, 9697.0, 10512.0, 11246.0), 
         "28800", array(5216.0, 7564.0, 8911.0, 9845.0, 10673.0, 11418.0), 
         "29400", array(5297.0, 7678.0, 9045.0, 9995.0, 10833.0, 11592.0), 
         "30000", array(5377.0, 7792.0, 9179.0, 10143.0, 10994.0, 11764.0), 
         "30600", array(5456.0, 7907.0, 9313.0, 10291.0, 11154.0, 11936.0), 
         "31200", array(5535.0, 8022.0, 9447.0, 10439.0, 11315.0, 12107.0), 
         "31800", array(5615.0, 8136.0, 9581.0, 10587.0, 11476.0, 12279.0), 
         "32400", array(5694.0, 8251.0, 9715.0, 10736.0, 11636.0, 12451.0), 
         "33000", array(5774.0, 8366.0, 9849.0, 10884.0, 11797.0, 12623.0), 
         "33600", array(5853.0, 8480.0, 9983.0, 11032.0, 11957.0, 12794.0), 
         "34200", array(5933.0, 8595.0, 10117.0, 11180.0, 12118.0, 12966.0), 
         "34800", array(6012.0, 8709.0, 10251.0, 11328.0, 12279.0, 13138.0), 
         "35400", array(6091.0, 8824.0, 10385.0, 11476.0, 12439.0, 13310.0), 
         "36000", array(6171.0, 8939.0, 10519.0, 11624.0, 12600.0, 13482.0), 
         "36600", array(6250.0, 9053.0, 10653.0, 11772.0, 12761.0, 13653.0), 
         "37200", array(6330.0, 9168.0, 10787.0, 11920.0, 12921.0, 13825.0), 
         "37800", array(6406.0, 9275.0, 10913.0, 12058.0, 13071.0, 13988.0), 
         "38400", array(6447.0, 9335.0, 10984.0, 12137.0, 13156.0, 14079.0), 
         "39000", array(6489.0, 9395.0, 11055.0, 12215.0, 13242.0, 14170.0), 
         "39600", array(6530.0, 9455.0, 11126.0, 12294.0, 13328.0, 14261.0), 
         "40200", array(6571.0, 9515.0, 11197.0, 12373.0, 13413.0, 14353.0), 
         "40800", array(6613.0, 9575.0, 11268.0, 12451.0, 13499.0, 14444.0), 
         "41400", array(6653.0, 9634.0, 11338.0, 12529.0, 13583.0, 14534.0), 
         "42000", array(6694.0, 9693.0, 11409.0, 12607.0, 13667.0, 14624.0), 
         "42600", array(6735.0, 9752.0, 11479.0, 12684.0, 13752.0, 14714.0), 
         "43200", array(6776.0, 9811.0, 11549.0, 12762.0, 13836.0, 14804.0), 
         "43800", array(6817.0, 9871.0, 11619.0, 12840.0, 13921.0, 14894.0), 
         "44400", array(6857.0, 9930.0, 11690.0, 12917.0, 14005.0, 14985.0), 
         "45000", array(6898.0, 9989.0, 11760.0, 12995.0, 14090.0, 15075.0), 
         "45600", array(6939.0, 10049.0, 11830.0, 13073.0, 14174.0, 15165.0), 
         "46200", array(6978.0, 10103.0, 11897.0, 13146.0, 14251.0, 15250.0), 
         "46800", array(7013.0, 10150.0, 11949.0, 13203.0, 14313.0, 15316.0), 
         "47400", array(7048.0, 10197.0, 12000.0, 13260.0, 14375.0, 15382.0), 
         "48000", array(7083.0, 10245.0, 12052.0, 13317.0, 14437.0, 15448.0), 
         "48600", array(7117.0, 10292.0, 12103.0, 13374.0, 14498.0, 15514.0), 
         "49200", array(7152.0, 10339.0, 12155.0, 13432.0, 14560.0, 15580.0), 
         "49800", array(7187.0, 10386.0, 12206.0, 13489.0, 14622.0, 15646.0), 
         "50400", array(7222.0, 10433.0, 12258.0, 13546.0, 14684.0, 15712.0), 
         "51000", array(7257.0, 10481.0, 12309.0, 13603.0, 14745.0, 15778.0), 
         "51600", array(7291.0, 10528.0, 12360.0, 13660.0, 14807.0, 15844.0), 
         "52200", array(7326.0, 10575.0, 12412.0, 13717.0, 14869.0, 15910.0), 
         "52800", array(7361.0, 10622.0, 12463.0, 13774.0, 14931.0, 15976.0), 
         "53400", array(7396.0, 10669.0, 12515.0, 13832.0, 14992.0, 16042.0), 
         "54000", array(7431.0, 10717.0, 12566.0, 13889.0, 15054.0, 16108.0), 
         "54600", array(7468.0, 10765.0, 12622.0, 13946.0, 15120.0, 16178.0), 
         "55200", array(7524.0, 10845.0, 12716.0, 14050.0, 15232.0, 16298.0), 
         "55800", array(7582.0, 10929.0, 12814.0, 14159.0, 15350.0, 16425.0), 
         "56400", array(7643.0, 11016.0, 12918.0, 14273.0, 15474.0, 16558.0), 
         "57000", array(7704.0, 11104.0, 13021.0, 14388.0, 15598.0, 16691.0), 
         "57600", array(7765.0, 11192.0, 13125.0, 14502.0, 15722.0, 16824.0), 
         "58200", array(7825.0, 11277.0, 13225.0, 14613.0, 15842.0, 16953.0), 
         "58800", array(7883.0, 11361.0, 13324.0, 14723.0, 15961.0, 17079.0), 
         "59400", array(7941.0, 11445.0, 13423.0, 14832.0, 16079.0, 17206.0), 
         "60000", array(8000.0, 11529.0, 13522.0, 14941.0, 16197.0, 17333.0), 
         "60600", array(8058.0, 11612.0, 13620.0, 15050.0, 16315.0, 17460.0), 
         "61200", array(8116.0, 11696.0, 13719.0, 15160.0, 16433.0, 17587.0), 
         "61800", array(8175.0, 11780.0, 13818.0, 15269.0, 16552.0, 17714.0), 
         "62400", array(8233.0, 11864.0, 13917.0, 15378.0, 16670.0, 17840.0), 
         "63000", array(8288.0, 11945.0, 14011.0, 15481.0, 16783.0, 17958.0), 
         "63600", array(8344.0, 12024.0, 14102.0, 15582.0, 16893.0, 18075.0), 
         "64200", array(8399.0, 12103.0, 14194.0, 15683.0, 17002.0, 18193.0), 
         "64800", array(8454.0, 12183.0, 14285.0, 15784.0, 17111.0, 18310.0), 
         "65400", array(8510.0, 12262.0, 14376.0, 15885.0, 17220.0, 18427.0), 
         "66000", array(8565.0, 12341.0, 14468.0, 15986.0, 17330.0, 18544.0), 
         "66600", array(8620.0, 12421.0, 14559.0, 16087.0, 17439.0, 18661.0), 
         "67200", array(8676.0, 12500.0, 14650.0, 16188.0, 17548.0, 18778.0), 
         "67800", array(8731.0, 12579.0, 14741.0, 16289.0, 17657.0, 18895.0), 
         "68400", array(8786.0, 12659.0, 14833.0, 16390.0, 17767.0, 19012.0), 
         "69000", array(8842.0, 12738.0, 14924.0, 16491.0, 17876.0, 19129.0), 
         "69600", array(8897.0, 12817.0, 15015.0, 16592.0, 17985.0, 19246.0), 
         "70200", array(8953.0, 12897.0, 15107.0, 16693.0, 18094.0, 19363.0), 
         "70800", array(9008.0, 12974.0, 15196.0, 16791.0, 18201.0, 19476.0), 
         "71400", array(9060.0, 13047.0, 15281.0, 16885.0, 18302.0, 19585.0), 
         "72000", array(9111.0, 13120.0, 15366.0, 16979.0, 18404.0, 19694.0), 
         "72600", array(9163.0, 13194.0, 15451.0, 17073.0, 18506.0, 19803.0), 
         "73200", array(9214.0, 13267.0, 15536.0, 17167.0, 18608.0, 19912.0), 
         "73800", array(9266.0, 13340.0, 15621.0, 17261.0, 18709.0, 20021.0), 
         "74400", array(9318.0, 13413.0, 15706.0, 17355.0, 18811.0, 20130.0), 
         "75000", array(9369.0, 13487.0, 15791.0, 17449.0, 18913.0, 20239.0), 
         "75600", array(9421.0, 13560.0, 15876.0, 17543.0, 19015.0, 20347.0), 
         "76200", array(9473.0, 13633.0, 15961.0, 17636.0, 19116.0, 20456.0), 
         "76800", array(9524.0, 13707.0, 16046.0, 17730.0, 19218.0, 20565.0), 
         "77400", array(9576.0, 13780.0, 16131.0, 17824.0, 19320.0, 20674.0), 
         "78000", array(9627.0, 13853.0, 16216.0, 17918.0, 19422.0, 20783.0), 
         "78600", array(9679.0, 13927.0, 16300.0, 18012.0, 19523.0, 20892.0), 
         "79200", array(9731.0, 14000.0, 16385.0, 18106.0, 19625.0, 21001.0), 
         "79800", array(9782.0, 14073.0, 16470.0, 18200.0, 19727.0, 21109.0), 
         "80400", array(9834.0, 14147.0, 16555.0, 18294.0, 19829.0, 21218.0), 
         "81000", array(9885.0, 14220.0, 16640.0, 18387.0, 19930.0, 21326.0), 
         "81600", array(9936.0, 14292.0, 16723.0, 18480.0, 20030.0, 21434.0), 
         "82200", array(9987.0, 14364.0, 16807.0, 18573.0, 20131.0, 21541.0), 
         "82800", array(10038.0, 14439.0, 16891.0, 18665.0, 20235.0, 21651.0), 
         "83400", array(10090.0, 14514.0, 16979.0, 18762.0, 20340.0, 21763.0), 
         "84000", array(10142.0, 14589.0, 17066.0, 18859.0, 20444.0, 21875.0), 
         "84600", array(10194.0, 14663.0, 17154.0, 18956.0, 20549.0, 21987.0), 
         "85200", array(10246.0, 14738.0, 17241.0, 19052.0, 20653.0, 22099.0), 
         "85800", array(10298.0, 14813.0, 17329.0, 19149.0, 20758.0, 22211.0), 
         "86400", array(10350.0, 14887.0, 17417.0, 19246.0, 20863.0, 22323.0), 
         "87000", array(10403.0, 14962.0, 17504.0, 19343.0, 20967.0, 22435.0), 
         "87600", array(10455.0, 15037.0, 17592.0, 19440.0, 21072.0, 22547.0), 
         "88200", array(10507.0, 15111.0, 17679.0, 19537.0, 21176.0, 22659.0), 
         "88800", array(10559.0, 15186.0, 17767.0, 19633.0, 21281.0, 22771.0), 
         "89400", array(10611.0, 15261.0, 17855.0, 19730.0, 21386.0, 22883.0), 
         "90000", array(10663.0, 15335.0, 17942.0, 19827.0, 21490.0, 22995.0), 
         "90600", array(10715.0, 15410.0, 18030.0, 19924.0, 21595.0, 23107.0), 
         "91200", array(10767.0, 15485.0, 18118.0, 20021.0, 21700.0, 23219.0), 
         "91800", array(10819.0, 15559.0, 18205.0, 20118.0, 21804.0, 23331.0), 
         "92400", array(10872.0, 15634.0, 18293.0, 20215.0, 21909.0, 23443.0), 
         "93000", array(10924.0, 15709.0, 18380.0, 20311.0, 22013.0, 23555.0), 
         "93600", array(10976.0, 15783.0, 18468.0, 20408.0, 22118.0, 23667.0), 
         "94200", array(11028.0, 15858.0, 18556.0, 20505.0, 22223.0, 23779.0), 
         "94800", array(11080.0, 15933.0, 18643.0, 20602.0, 22327.0, 23891.0), 
         "95400", array(11132.0, 16007.0, 18731.0, 20699.0, 22432.0, 24003.0), 
         "96000", array(11184.0, 16082.0, 18818.0, 20796.0, 22536.0, 24115.0), 
         "96600", array(11236.0, 16157.0, 18906.0, 20892.0, 22641.0, 24227.0), 
         "97200", array(11289.0, 16231.0, 18994.0, 20989.0, 22746.0, 24339.0), 
         "97800", array(11341.0, 16306.0, 19081.0, 21086.0, 22850.0, 24451.0), 
         "98400", array(11393.0, 16381.0, 19169.0, 21183.0, 22955.0, 24563.0), 
         "99000", array(11446.0, 16450.0, 19255.0, 21279.0, 23062.0, 24676.0), 
         "99600", array(11491.0, 16516.0, 19334.0, 21366.0, 23156.0, 24777.0), 
         "100200", array(11536.0, 16583.0, 19413.0, 21453.0, 23250.0, 24878.0), 
         "100800", array(11581.0, 16649.0, 19491.0, 21539.0, 23345.0, 24978.0), 
         "101400", array(11625.0, 16714.0, 19569.0, 21625.0, 23437.0, 25077.0), 
         "102000", array(11670.0, 16779.0, 19646.0, 21710.0, 23530.0, 25177.0), 
         "102600", array(11714.0, 16844.0, 19724.0, 21796.0, 23623.0, 25276.0), 
         "103200", array(11759.0, 16909.0, 19801.0, 21881.0, 23715.0, 25375.0), 
         "103800", array(11803.0, 16974.0, 19879.0, 21967.0, 23808.0, 25475.0), 
         "104400", array(11847.0, 17039.0, 19956.0, 22052.0, 23901.0, 25574.0), 
         "105000", array(11892.0, 17104.0, 20034.0, 22138.0, 23994.0, 25673.0), 
         "105600", array(11934.0, 17167.0, 20108.0, 22220.0, 24083.0, 25769.0), 
         "106200", array(11979.0, 17232.0, 20186.0, 22305.0, 24176.0, 25868.0), 
         "106800", array(12023.0, 17297.0, 20263.0, 22391.0, 24269.0, 25968.0), 
         "107400", array(12068.0, 17362.0, 20341.0, 22476.0, 24361.0, 26067.0), 
         "108000", array(12110.0, 17425.0, 20415.0, 22559.0, 24451.0, 26162.0), 
         "108600", array(12155.0, 17490.0, 20493.0, 22644.0, 24543.0, 26262.0), 
         "109200", array(12199.0, 17555.0, 20570.0, 22730.0, 24636.0, 26361.0), 
         "109800", array(12243.0, 17620.0, 20648.0, 22815.0, 24729.0, 26460.0), 
         "110400", array(12286.0, 17683.0, 20722.0, 22897.0, 24818.0, 26556.0), 
         "111000", array(12331.0, 17748.0, 20800.0, 22983.0, 24911.0, 26655.0), 
         "111600", array(12375.0, 17813.0, 20877.0, 23068.0, 25004.0, 26755.0), 
         "112200", array(12419.0, 17878.0, 20955.0, 23154.0, 25096.0, 26854.0), 
         "112800", array(12462.0, 17941.0, 21029.0, 23236.0, 25186.0, 26949.0), 
         "113400", array(12506.0, 18006.0, 21107.0, 23322.0, 25278.0, 27049.0), 
         "114000", array(12551.0, 18071.0, 21184.0, 23407.0, 25371.0, 27148.0), 
         "114600", array(12595.0, 18136.0, 21262.0, 23493.0, 25464.0, 27247.0), 
         "115200", array(12640.0, 18202.0, 21339.0, 23578.0, 25557.0, 27347.0), 
         "115800", array(12682.0, 18264.0, 21414.0, 23660.0, 25646.0, 27442.0), 
         "116400", array(12727.0, 18329.0, 21491.0, 23746.0, 25739.0, 27542.0), 
         "117000", array(12771.0, 18394.0, 21569.0, 23831.0, 25832.0, 27641.0), 
         "117600", array(12815.0, 18460.0, 21646.0, 23917.0, 25924.0, 27740.0), 
         "118200", array(12858.0, 18522.0, 21721.0, 23999.0, 26013.0, 27836.0), 
         "118800", array(12902.0, 18587.0, 21798.0, 24084.0, 26106.0, 27935.0), 
         "119400", array(12947.0, 18652.0, 21876.0, 24170.0, 26199.0, 28034.0), 
         "120000", array(12991.0, 18718.0, 21953.0, 24256.0, 26292.0, 28134.0), 
         "120600", array(13034.0, 18780.0, 22028.0, 24338.0, 26381.0, 28229.0), 
         "121200", array(13078.0, 18845.0, 22105.0, 24423.0, 26474.0, 28329.0), 
         "121800", array(13123.0, 18910.0, 22183.0, 24509.0, 26567.0, 28428.0), 
         "122400", array(13167.0, 18976.0, 22260.0, 24594.0, 26659.0, 28527.0), 
         "123000", array(13210.0, 19038.0, 22335.0, 24676.0, 26749.0, 28623.0), 
         "123600", array(13254.0, 19103.0, 22412.0, 24762.0, 26841.0, 28722.0), 
         "124200", array(13299.0, 19168.0, 22490.0, 24847.0, 26934.0, 28821.0), 
         "124800", array(13343.0, 19234.0, 22567.0, 24933.0, 27027.0, 28921.0), 
         "125400", array(13386.0, 19296.0, 22642.0, 25015.0, 27116.0, 29016.0), 
         "126000", array(13430.0, 19361.0, 22719.0, 25101.0, 27209.0, 29115.0), 
         "126600", array(13474.0, 19426.0, 22797.0, 25186.0, 27302.0, 29215.0), 
         "127200", array(13519.0, 19492.0, 22874.0, 25272.0, 27395.0, 29314.0), 
         "127800", array(13561.0, 19554.0, 22949.0, 25354.0, 27484.0, 29410.0), 
         "128400", array(13606.0, 19619.0, 23026.0, 25439.0, 27576.0, 29509.0), 
         "129000", array(13650.0, 19684.0, 23104.0, 25525.0, 27669.0, 29608.0), 
         "129600", array(13695.0, 19750.0, 23181.0, 25610.0, 27762.0, 29708.0), 
         "130200", array(13739.0, 19815.0, 23259.0, 25696.0, 27855.0, 29807.0), 
         "130800", array(13783.0, 19879.0, 23335.0, 25780.0, 27946.0, 29905.0), 
         "131400", array(13828.0, 19945.0, 23414.0, 25868.0, 28041.0, 30007.0), 
         "132000", array(13874.0, 20012.0, 23494.0, 25955.0, 28136.0, 30108.0), 
         "132600", array(13919.0, 20079.0, 23573.0, 26043.0, 28231.0, 30210.0), 
         "133200", array(13963.0, 20143.0, 23649.0, 26127.0, 28323.0, 30308.0), 
         "133800", array(14008.0, 20210.0, 23729.0, 26215.0, 28418.0, 30410.0), 
         "134400", array(14054.0, 20276.0, 23808.0, 26302.0, 28513.0, 30511.0), 
         "135000", array(14099.0, 20343.0, 23887.0, 26390.0, 28608.0, 30613.0), 
         "135600", array(14143.0, 20407.0, 23964.0, 26474.0, 28699.0, 30711.0), 
         "136200", array(14188.0, 20474.0, 24043.0, 26561.0, 28794.0, 30813.0), 
         "136800", array(14234.0, 20541.0, 24123.0, 26649.0, 28889.0, 30914.0), 
         "137400", array(14279.0, 20607.0, 24202.0, 26737.0, 28984.0, 31016.0), 
         "138000", array(14323.0, 20671.0, 24278.0, 26821.0, 29075.0, 31114.0), 
         "138600", array(14368.0, 20738.0, 24358.0, 26908.0, 29170.0, 31215.0), 
         "139200", array(14414.0, 20805.0, 24437.0, 26996.0, 29265.0, 31317.0), 
         "139800", array(14459.0, 20872.0, 24516.0, 27083.0, 29361.0, 31419.0), 
         "140400", array(14503.0, 20936.0, 24593.0, 27168.0, 29452.0, 31517.0), 
         "141000", array(14549.0, 21002.0, 24672.0, 27255.0, 29547.0, 31618.0), 
         "141600", array(14594.0, 21069.0, 24751.0, 27343.0, 29642.0, 31720.0), 
         "142200", array(14639.0, 21136.0, 24831.0, 27430.0, 29737.0, 31822.0), 
         "142800", array(14683.0, 21200.0, 24907.0, 27515.0, 29828.0, 31920.0), 
         "143400", array(14729.0, 21267.0, 24986.0, 27602.0, 29923.0, 32021.0), 
         "144000", array(14774.0, 21333.0, 25066.0, 27690.0, 30018.0, 32123.0), 
         "144600", array(14820.0, 21400.0, 25145.0, 27777.0, 30113.0, 32225.0), 
         "145200", array(14865.0, 21467.0, 25225.0, 27865.0, 30208.0, 32327.0), 
         "145800", array(14909.0, 21531.0, 25301.0, 27949.0, 30300.0, 32424.0), 
         "146400", array(14963.0, 21596.0, 25377.0, 28041.0, 30396.0, 32526.0), 
         "147000", array(15006.0, 21659.0, 25452.0, 28124.0, 30486.0, 32622.0), 
         "147600", array(15049.0, 21722.0, 25527.0, 28207.0, 30576.0, 32718.0), 
         "148200", array(15090.0, 21782.0, 25599.0, 28286.0, 30662.0, 32810.0), 
         "148800", array(15133.0, 21845.0, 25674.0, 28369.0, 30752.0, 32907.0), 
         "149400", array(15176.0, 21908.0, 25749.0, 28452.0, 30842.0, 33003.0), 
         "150000", array(15218.0, 21971.0, 25823.0, 28534.0, 30931.0, 33099.0));



    function BasicObligation($NoChildren, $Income, $BasicSkedValues,$BasicSkedMatrix){
        $ArrayChildren = $NoChildren-1;
        $Income = (string)$Income;
        $closestMatrix = getClosest($Income,$BasicSkedValues);

        $Obligation = $BasicSkedMatrix[getClosest($Income,$BasicSkedValues)][$ArrayChildren];
        print_r($Obligation);
        return $Obligation;

        // return $BasicSkedMatrix[getClosest($Income,$BasicSkedValues)][$ArrayChildren];
    };

    BasicObligation(3, 90000, $BasicSkedValues,$BasicSkedMatrix);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP Indexed arrays should be defined like this:

```
array(key=>value,key=>value,key=>value,etc.);
```

e.g.

```
$BasicSkedMatrix = array(
             "0" => array(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), 
          "6600" => array(600.0, 600.0, 600.0, 600.0, 600.0, 600.0), 
          ...
         "149400" => array(15176.0, 21908.0, 25749.0, 28452.0, 30842.0, 33003.0), 
         "150000" => array(15218.0, 21971.0, 25823.0, 28534.0, 30931.0, 33099.0));
```

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you!